# Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I am really lost on this question. I am not even sure where to start. Can somebody help me with step by step instructions on how to approach and understand the problem?

> Define a linear transformation $T:P_1\rightarrow P_2$ by setting $T(p(x))=p(x)+x p(x)$. Find the matrix of $T$ if you use the basis $B=\{1,1+x\}$ for the domain $P_1$ and the basis $C=\{1-x,x,x^2+x\}$ for the codomain $P_2$.

All I know for sure is that the standard basis is $\{1, x, x^2\}$, and if this is an eigenbasis for $T$ then $T$ is diagonalizable.

Much thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Since the domain and codomain of $T$ are different, it makes no sense to write about eigenvectors, eigenvalues, eigenbases, and diagonalizability.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_1=1,e_2=1+x$ be basis of $P_1$,

$e_1'=1-x,e'_2=x, e'_3=x^2+x$ be basis of $P_2$

Then

$T(e_1)=1+x=1-x +2x=e_1'+2e_2'$,

$T(e_2)=(1+x)+x(1+x)=(1-x)+2x+(x^2+x)=e_1'+2e_2'+e_3'$

So we have

$T\left[\begin{array}{}
   e_1 \\
   e_2 \\
  \end{array} \right]=A_T\left[\begin{array}{}
   e_1' \\
   e_2' \\
   e_3' \\
  \end{array} \right]$, where
$   A_T=
  \left[ \begin{array}{}
   1 & 2 & 0 \\
   1 & 2 & 1 \\
  \end{array}  \right]
$

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding to my question, I was wondering how did the 1+x turn to 1-x+2x then e_1+2e_2?

Comment: It is simple algebra, x=(-x)+2x. Then by definition of e_1 and e_2 at the beginning.